# Failure to compile Kobold2d with Xcode 4.6 DP3

Tags: ios, xcode

So, I just installed Kobold2d and now I can't seem to even run the example hello world code, can anybody help me?
The error I'm getting is
Command /Applications/Xcode46-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Comment: Can you post some code? Did you set your linker flags correctly in the Build settings? Did you set the .m file targets right?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem. This problem happened because the last version of Xcode4.6 is not compatible with kobold2d you have right now. So to fix this problem you need to download the last version of kobold2d with the [link](http://www.kobold2d.com/display/KKSITE/Kobold2D+Download?atl_token=cbc4a35933395b69dd315217d820cb9834eb4918).

thanks hope this help.